# ! Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra }

Tags: missing

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=.4,  
contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{frame}}
}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.2cm}}







\begin{document}
\pagecolor{brown}

\begingroup
  \colorlet{darkgray}{black}
\title{Diary \# 1 \\ 2/4/22 - 31/12/22 }
    \author{Bhaskar Vashishth}
    \date{2022}

   
    \endgroup
    \maketitle
    %\nopagecolor
    
    

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 2 (Saturday)}{\color{teal}{\textit{Sleepless but discharge day}}
\colorlet{green}{red} 

today. \dSmiley




\noindent \textit{Au revior!} \textit{\color{olive}{Good Night!}} 
    
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 3 (Sunday)}{\textit{\color{cyan}{What a Day!}}}
hjkl}


 \noindent    \textit{\color{violet}{Good Night!}}
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April-4 (Monday)}{\color{brown}{\textit{A good Day}}}
 \noindent \\
    \vskip 3mm
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    level 1/.style = {red, sibling distance = 3.5cm}
]

\node {This is me}
    child {node [brown]{Happy}}
    child {node [teal]{Sad!}}
    child {node [cyan]{Anxious}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

I choose happy.

 \color{blue} {\textsc{Good Night!}} \Sleepey[2][darkgray].
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April- 5 (Tuesday)}{\color{green}{\textit{An wonderful Day}}}
Everything is fine.
 \textit{\color{red} GOOD NIGHT!}
\end{loggentry}

\end{document}
```

***What am I missing here?***

Comment: check your braces. There is a closing brace missing at the first \begin{logentry}, and the one after hjkl is too much.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I cant seem to find any extra brace. can you please answer the correct code. I am weak in Latex.

Comment: count the braces on this line `\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 2 (Saturday)}{\color{teal}{\textit{Sleepless but discharge day}}`. And get yourself an editor which highlights matching braces

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have Texmaker. It highlights everything correctly in this line. May be I am being too dumb. Please help.

Comment: as I wrote: there is a closing brace missing, so simply add one at the end.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 
\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 2 (Saturday)}{\color{teal}{\textit{Sleepless but discharge day}}}
\colorlet{green}{red} 
This shows the same error

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. At least this compiles (I don't have the `emerald` package so uncommented it. Then fixed a lot of missing `}` or irrelevant `}`'s

I have no idea if it looks like it is suppose to.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
%\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=.4,  
contents=}


\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.2cm}}



\begin{document}
\pagecolor{brown}

\begingroup
  \colorlet{darkgray}{black}
  \title{Diary \# 1 \\ 2/4/22 - 31/12/22 }
    \author{Bhaskar Vashishth}
    \date{2022}

   
    \endgroup
    \maketitle
    %\nopagecolor
    
     

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 2 (Saturday)}{\color{teal}{\textit{Sleepless but discharge day}}}
\colorlet{green}{red} 

today. \dSmiley




\noindent \textit{Au revior!} \textit{\color{olive}{Good Night!}} 
    
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April 3 (Sunday)}{\textit{\color{cyan}{What a Day!}}}
hjkl


 \noindent    \textit{\color{violet}{Good Night!}}
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April-4 (Monday)}{\color{brown}{\textit{A good Day}}}
 \noindent \\
    \vskip 3mm
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    level 1/.style = {red, sibling distance = 3.5cm}
    ]

    \node {This is me}
    child {node [brown]{Happy}}
    child {node [teal]{Sad!}}
    child {node [cyan]{Anxious}};
    
  \end{tikzpicture}

  I choose happy.

  \color{blue} {\textsc{Good Night!}} \Sleepey[2][darkgray].
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2022-April- 5 (Tuesday)}{\color{green}{\textit{An wonderful Day}}}
Everything is fine.
 \textit{\color{red} GOOD NIGHT!}
\end{loggentry}

\end{document}
```